# Was there a group of Jews who would fast on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, fast-days, oneg-shabbat

I heard from a friend with Russian Jewish ancestry that her ancestors used to fast for the rest of Shabbat after Shabbat dinner. All the research I’ve done has yielded what I already knew that Jews aren’t supposed to fast during Shabbat due to Oneg Shabbat and I found in Mishnah Ta’anit chapter 4 3:1 that members of the Maamad would also refrain from fasting on Friday and Sunday. My friend is a goy so it might just be a misunderstanding but I’m really curious if there is some group of Jews who do this.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95635/does-judaism-forbid-fasting-on-fridays-and-saturdays-if-so-where-is-this-rule#:~:text=Fasting%20is%20forbidden%20on%20Shabbat,is%20required%20to%20enjoy%20Shabbat.